# Application frame not being set to full screen

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

My video application is in landscape，I am doing the following to make it fullScreen.

`self.playerView.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;`

It changed and then turned back quickly. Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: You used `AutoLayout` in your view isn`t it?

Comment: Yes，and I should find the problem.Because I added a view on the playerView,they all use `AutoLayout`,so this strange phenomenon happened.Thank you all the same.